# .Net/C# throw an exception when a method is accessed concurrently

Tags: c#, concurrency

I'm writing some fragile multi-threaded code and there is a part of the code that must *not* be run concurrently, ever. Not even inside a `lock` statement, otherwise my application would be in a bad state.

I would like to check for this as efficiently and elegantly as possible. I know I can throw a class that tracks threads and locks but that is bit of a shotgun to hammer a nail. What is the best way to do this in .Net/C#?

Question: Is it possible to guard an instance method such that if there is concurrent access, an exception is thrown?

Also, I'm targeting the Portable Class Library, if that matters.

Comment: Do you want to disallow reenterant code (i.e. a recursive or indirectly recursive call on the same thread) too?

Comment: @MatthewWatson no, it is not recursive, it's just a very straight forward method, but it must be run serially, and never from different threads (from the ctor/first call).

Comment: So does that mean that you want to show an error if it IS called re-entrantly? Or do you just want to ignore that possibility?

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, that'd be an error. I'd like to **not** ignore the possibility, and scream loudly if that happens.

Comment: Ok in that case just using the `Monitor` solution will be insufficient because it allows re-entrant calls.

Comment: Why not just use a lock, and immediately after acquiring the lock, check the conditions you want (e.g. thread id matches thread id recorded by the constructor) and throw a custom exception if they fail?

Comment: Using a `lock` will block if any other thread has already acquired the lock and enter only once the other thread has released the lock. How will that help the OP?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Monitor.TryEnter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tssbxcw(v=vs.110).aspx) to detect if a `lock` object was taken already:

```
public static object syncRoot = new object();
public void X()
{
    bool acquiredLock = false;
    try
    {
        Monitor.TryEnter(syncRoot, ref wasLockTaken);
        if (acquiredLock)
        {
            // If we're here, the lock was taken.
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (acquiredLock)
            Monitor.Exit(syncRoot);
    }
}
```

In case it is, `TryEnter` will immediatly return `false`, and you can do whatever you'd like inside.

**Edit:**

Due to the fact that you say re-entrency might be a problem, you can use a `SpinLock` as [provided by @MatthewWatson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34117731/1870803), or use a [`Semaphore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static object syncRoot = new object();
public static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1);

public static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        if (!semaphore.WaitOne(0))
        {
            // If we're here, the lock was taken.
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh nice. Does this means I need to `finally{ Monitor.Exit }` too?

Comment: @chakrit Yes, you will need that `finally`, otherwise the Monitor will never be exited.

Comment: Since the OP also wants to display an error on re-entrant calls, you will also want to add some code to detect that case. I suggest adding a static int and using `if (Interlocked.Increment(ref callCount) > 1) throw new InvalidOperationException("some message"));` inside the `if (acquiredLock)`. You'd also need to add a `finally` to call `Interlocked.Decrement()` when exiting too.

Comment: @MatthewWatson but `if (acquiredLock)` already signals that this is method is concurrently invoked. Why add another check?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The OP said he wanted to protect against re-entrant calls from the same thread, i.e. a directly or indirectly recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to protect against re-entrant calls from the same thread as well as against concurrent calls from multiple threads, you can use a [`SpinLock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinlock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This will protect against concurrent AND re-entrant calls.

Here's a sample program. It will throw an exception due to multithreaded access being detected.

If you change the line indicated by a comment, it will throw a different exception due to a re-entrant call being detected.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static SpinLock locker = new SpinLock(enableThreadOwnerTracking:true);

        static void Main()
        {
            var task1 = Task.Run(() => test(0)); // Change to test(1) to test re-entrant protection.
            var task2 = Task.Run(() => test(0));

            Console.WriteLine("Started threads. Waiting for them to exit.");

            Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);

            Console.WriteLine("Waited for threads to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void test(int n)
        {
            bool lockTaken = false;

            try
            {
                locker.TryEnter(0, ref lockTaken);

                if (lockTaken)
                {
                    if (n > 0)
                        test(n - 1);

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Throwing exception");
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Error: Multithreaded access to test() detected");
                }
            }

            finally
            {
                if (lockTaken)
                    locker.Exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a solution that works for the PCL? since PCL doesn't have `SpinLock`

Comment: @chakrit In a comment to Yuval's answer I mention how to use `Interlocked` to keep track of the recursion count.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way that can avoid all locks altogether:

```cs
int _countTaken = 0;

void Method()
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref _countTaken);
    try
    {
        if (_countTaken > 1)
            throw new Exception(...);
        DoStuff();
    }
    finally
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref _countTaken);
    }
}
```

This is guaranteed never to let two methods run `DoStuff()` at once, but has the disadvantage that if two threads call `Method()` at the same time, it's possible they'll both throw, rather than just the second.